# UIButton with an external website link but it is not responding to touches

Tags: swift, xcode, button, uikit, uibutton

I added a UIButton with an external website link but it is not responding to touches.

`@IBAction func onHavaDurumuHaberleriBtn(_ sender: Any) { UIApplication.shared.open(URL(string:"https://www.mgm.gov.tr/tahmin/gunluk-tahmin.aspx")! as URL, options: [:], completionHandler: nil)`

I also added     `@IBOutlet weak var onHavaDurumuHaberleriBtn: UIButton!` at top.

I'm using Xcode 14.3.1 version.

Here is my code and application's look:

[Screenshot of my App and codes](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ubmvv.jpg)

Comment: Did you connect the `onHavaDurumuHaberleriBtn` IBAction to the button's "touch up inside" event? Is the button's constraints such that it is fully within its parent view?

Comment: Yes, I connected the `onHavaDurumuHaberleriBtn` while creating the codes of the button with the touch up inside event. Then I connected the button to `@IBOutlet weak var onHavaDurumuHaberleriBtn: UIButton!`

Comment: Here is the screenshot where I connected both of them, is it correct? https://i.imgur.com/vkXTapw.png